# Embedded room entity field in retrofit response object not initialized at runtime

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room

I have a `CurrentWeatherResponse` object that contains the JSON data recovered from a weather API using Retrofit. Here's the JSON response format:

```
{
"latitude": 37.8267,
"longitude": -122.4233,
"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
"currently": {
  "time": 1587054875,
  "summary": "Mostly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
  "nearestStormDistance": 107,
  "nearestStormBearing": 119,
  "precipIntensity": 0,
  "precipProbability": 0,
  "temperature": 11.49,
  "apparentTemperature": 11.49,
  "dewPoint": 10.14,
  "humidity": 0.91,
  "pressure": 1012.9,
  "windSpeed": 2.73,
  "windGust": 3.84,
  "windBearing": 171,
  "cloudCover": 0.64,
  "uvIndex": 2,
  "visibility": 16.093,
  "ozone": 360.9
  },
"offset": -7
}
```

Inside of the `CurrentWeatherResponse` i have two fields `currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry` & `val location: WeatherLocation` respectively. Each one of those fields is a room `@Entity` class. Now i noticed that although the `"currently"` json data is passed successfully into the `CurrentWeatherEntry` field, the `@Embedded` location `WeatherLocation` field is never initialized. When i run the app or use the database inspector, i can see that the `WeatherLocation` entity doesn't even have its ID field initialized. What am i missing here?

CurrentWeatherResponse class :

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    // Tells GSON that the "currently" field of the JSON returned by the
    // API should be tied with our CurrentWeatherEntry data class
    @SerializedName("currently")
    val currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry,
    @Embedded
    val location: WeatherLocation
) {
    init {
        location.setEpochTimeVal(currentWeatherEntry.time)
    }
}
```

CurrentWeatherEntry entity:

```
const val CURRENT_WEATHER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeatherEntry(
    val time: Long, // epoch timestamp
    val icon: String,
    val summary: String,
    val precipProbability: Double,
    val temperature: Double
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id:Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}
```

WeatherLocaiton entity:

```
const val WEATHER_LOCATION_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "weather_location")
data class WeatherLocation(
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double,
    val timezone: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id:Int = WEATHER_LOCATION_ID

    private var epochTimeVal:Long = 0

    val zonedDateTime:ZonedDateTime
        get() {
            val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(this.epochTimeVal)
            val zoneId = ZoneId.of(timezone)
            return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant,zoneId)
        }

    fun setEpochTimeVal(time:Long) {
        this.epochTimeVal = time}
    fun getEpochTimeVal() : Long = epochTimeVal
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @MahdiRajabi stated, the `@Embedded` annotation is used by Room and not Gson. That means that the `latitude`,`longitude` & `timezone` fields that were returned from the JSON response into the `CurrentWeatherResponse` class, were simply ignored and the `location:WeatherLocation` field was simply assigned `null`. I solved my issue by explicitly defining the `latitude`,`longitude` & `timezone` fields in the `CurrentWeatherResponse` and then returning an instance of `WeatherLocation` when the `location` field is accessed using the getter. Now everything works as expected!

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    // Tells GSON that the "currently" field of the JSON returned by the
    // API should be tied with our CurrentWeatherEntry data class
    @SerializedName("currently")
    val currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry,
    val latitude:Double,
    val longitude:Double,
    val timezone:String
) {
    val location:WeatherLocation
        get() = WeatherLocation(latitude,longitude,timezone,currentWeatherEntry.time)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem, I have to say that `@Embedded` annotation is `Room`'s annotation, not `Gson`'s annotation. So it won't play rule to convert your response to Kotlin data object by Retrofit.

`@Embedded` annotation only is visible for Room Dao class to convert relational data base to your convenient object model.

So you need to write your own `TypeConvertor` for Gson.